# Framework procedure to create private framework with internal Pods for different 3rd party library used

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I am developing a private framework to source to our clients for their project so they can just drag and drop in their project and start using.

To avoid unwanted library imports references paths set and Add to build settings work, I referred that Building the framework to organise deliverables is much better solution which can cater for the Watch OS, IPods, Ipad,IPhones all in one.

I wanted to create a universal framework with pods used by the other 3rd party. Can any one please guide me through the process how I can achieve this with making it compact in size and delivered with no source code exposed except my interface files only.

Structure expected.

MYCustomFramework

- -----Version
- --------- Some Assets Bundle
- --------- 3rd Party Pods Libraries
- --------------- XMPP Framework using Pods
- --------------- Documentation Framework
- --------------- Logs Framework  -

Then I want to add this framework to My Test project which will have the Pods of its self

MyTestProject.xcworkspace
MyTestProject.xcproj
MYCustomFramework.framework -- This will have all the below bracket stuff compiled inside so no source exposed except interfaces.
{

- -----Version
- --------- Some Assets Bundle
- --------- 3rd Party Pods Libraries
- --------------- XMPP Framework using Pods
- --------------- Documentation Framework
- --------------- Logs Framework
  }

How to achieve this and make it with less size as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various trials I finally made this work in following manner.

1) Pods (Test Project released) cannot have Pods for the library with many third parties. 2 Workspace conflict and which one to use would be tedious.

2) Create a test project and implemented Pods for this test project and opened it using workspace.

3) Use the XMPP Framework library and extracted folders and headers without Pods.

4) Create a Cocoa-touch Framework and dragged this XMPPFramework folder without using Pods.

5) Similarly used manual process to integrate other libraries in My Cocoa-Touch Framework

6) Compiled My Framework and generated the mycustomframework.framework for (Device & Simulator)

7) Optionally I can use LIPO now to make the aggregated target to make sure all the XMPP and other 3rd party libraries  headers are private inside my framework and only my exposed public header files are available for test project integration.

8) Worked out to run my test project either by just dragging the compiled '.framework' file or dragging library project inside my test project so can debug my library code as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this guide, you have to add your spec repo to pods repos as well
https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

EDITED:

We have a internally wrapped Fabric POD which just delivers the Fabric.framework we get from Fabric (this was before Fabric had a public pod) here is our pod spec.
So in your repo you can build a .framework and deliver it the same way were wrapping Fabric

Hope this help

```
{
  "name": "InternalFabric",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "summary": "Fabric is a 3rd party library that gives us crash analytics.",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/myNameHere",
  "authors": "myNameHere",
  "license": {
    "type": "Copyright",
    "text": "\n Copyright Acme Inc. 2014\n For internal Acme use only. \n"
     },  
  "platforms": {
    "ios": "7.0"
  },
  "source": {
    "git": "https://github.com/ios-yourLibs/Fabric.git"
  },
  "requires_arc": true,
  "default_subspecs": "Core",
  "subspecs": [
      {
        "name": "Core",
        "vendored_frameworks": ["Fabric.framework","Crashlytics.framework"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Crashlytics",
        "dependencies": {
          "Fabric/Core": [

          ]
        },
        "vendored_frameworks": "Crashlytics.framework"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is just explaining the creating of the private framework but not my answer, I want to create my library so i decided to go with the framework approach. Then I require the XMPP Framework inside my library as dependancy which will point to specific version only. So My Pods should deliver a .framework to the enduser that have this inside embedded. How to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks David, I am bit new to this Pods specs stuff , although I think you got my point nearly matched so I will try to do this check and get back to you. By the way can we have a chat to get this guidance more clear. My id : vickydhas@rappier.com/ Skype: vickydhas